# form の value の値に空白が入ると，そこで区切られてしまう

Tags: php, html, form

### 問題の要約

`type = hidden` に設定した form 要素の value 属性に，`$_POST` 変数の値を格納したくて，次のようなコードを書きました．

```php
<input type="hidden" name="hogehoge" value= <?php echo $_POST['hogehoge'] ?>>
```

ところが，`$_POST['hogehoge']` に格納されているテキストに空白が入っていると，そこで値が区切られてしまい，想定したようには値が渡せなくなります．

具体的には，空白までのテキストだけが `value` に渡されてしまいます．

どのようにすれば，解決できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` を `echo` している php のコード全体をシングルクォートで囲ってください．

つまり，次のようにコードを修正してください．

```php
<input type="hidden" name="hogehoge" value= '<?php echo $_POST['hogehoge'] ?>'>
```

これで，空白文字が含まれていても全体が value に渡されるようになります．